# Entity framework CF model structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been working on this for a while now and i still haven't come up with a good idea.

I have the fallowing 3 types `Project`, `User` and `Result`. A user and a project can have multiple results. My problem now is that a result can be of multiple types (12 right now and that can change). I have no idea how i'm supposed to structure this the only things that this results have in common is a type and an Id and i want a table for each of the different 12 types.

So what i have until now is this.

**Project**

```
public class Project :ITypedEntity<ProjectType>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectType Type { get; set; }
    public string TitleEn { get; set; }
    public string TitleRo { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string ContractNo { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityField ActivityField {get;set;}
    public string SummaryEn { get; set; }
    public string SumarryRo { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsPartner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Team{get;set;}
    public string Website {get;set;}
    public ICollection<INamedEntity> Results;
}
```

**Result**

```
public class Result:ITypedEntity<ResultType>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public ResultType Type { get; set; }
    }
```

**User**

```
public class User:Person
    {
        public int CNP { get; set; }
        public virtual Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
        public bool IsUSAMV {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<INamedEntity> Results {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects {get;set;}
    }
```

I don't think this helps but i'll paste them anyway

```
public interface INamedEntity:IEntity
{
    string Name{get;set;}
}
public interface ITypedEntity<TType>:INamedEntity{
    TType Type { get; set; }
}
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Update 1**
Some results types

```
public class BookChapter:INamedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book {get;set;}
    public int PagesInChapter {get;set;}
    public string Pagination {get;set;}
}


public class Book:INamedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Authors { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Publisher Publisher {get;set;}
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public string Pagination { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
}


public class Patent:ITypedEntity<PatentType>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Authors { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Holder{get;set;}
    public string Number{get;set;}
    public virtual PatentType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry if the question is not clear, i'll update it with any other information you need.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into [table-per-hierarchy](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)?

Comment: @HenkMollema i have no idea what that is, i'll look into it and provide and get back to you thanks.

Comment: Could you show some of the result types you have? The complete classes please.

Comment: @HenkMollema posted some examples

Comment: Why don't they derive from `Result`?

Comment: @HenkMollema Because i didn't know if that was a good idea so i decided to make all of the implement the same interface

Comment: I was thinking the same @HenkMollema. Derive them from Result. May as well mark Result as Abstract, and go from there with the specs, and have your Results, as an ICollection<Result>